# how to insert property many-to-many relationship with entity framework and transaction

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I've got an table **Applicnt** -

id

Name

SrtusID --

Also I've got a table **ApplicantLanguages**

id

ApplicantID

LanguageID (many to many relationship)

So my question is when I try to add a an Applicant and his languages - shouldn't be that in transaction and is the proper way to be done

Thank you in advance!

```
public void AddApplicant(string FirstName, string  LastName, int StatusId,int AddressId, List<int>SelectedLanguages)
        {
            Applicant newApplicant = new Applicant { Name = FirstName, LastName = LastName,AddressesId = AddressId,StatusesId=StatusId };
            foreach (var item in SelectedLanguages)
            {
                newApplicant.Languages.Add(testEntity.Languages.Where(x=>x.id==item).FirstOrDefault());
            }
            testEntity.Applicant.Add(newApplicant);
            testEntity.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Looks OK. Anything that makes you hesitant?

Answer (score 0):

Having next model:

```
public class Applicant
{

    public int Id {get;set;}

    public string Name {get;set;}

    public virtual ICollection<ApplicantLanguage> Languages {get;set;}
}

public class ApplicantLanguage{

    public int Id{get;set;}

    [ForeignKey("Applicant")]
    public int ApplicantId{get;set;}

    public virtual Applicant {get;set;}

    [ForeignKey("Language")]
    public int LanguageId{get;set;}

    public virtual Language {get;set;}
}
```

you can add just do it next way

```
public void AddApplicant(string FirstName, string  LastName, int StatusId,int AddressId, List<int>SelectedLanguages)
{
    Applicant newApplicant = new Applicant { Name = FirstName, LastName = LastName,AddressesId = AddressId,StatusesId=StatusId };

    newApplicant.Languages.Add(SelectedLanguages.Select(langId=>new ApplicantLanguage{Applicant = newApplicant, LanguageId = langId})
    testEntity.Applicant.Add(newApplicant);
    testEntity.SaveChanges();
}
```